# Why do I get this in Eclipse, is this an error?

Tags: android, eclipse

[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

Answer (score 4):

Because all images should have a text descriptor.

It is for accessibility, so people with visual impairment can use the app (through Google's accessibility app which reads out the names of Views in the UI)

You should add the text, though if you do not want to (incorrect in my view) you could set it to "".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html